# UVM macros- SVTEST/SVTEST_END

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I read the following blog regarding axi driver:
http://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2016/08/testing-uvm-drivers-part-2.html?showComment=1471877179631#c7809781639091671746

In this blog there are several uses in SVTEST/SVTEST_END macros. I can't find explenation regarding those macros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe he is using a library called **SVUNIT** See http://www.agilesoc.com/open-source-projects/svunit/svunit-getting-started/